# URL of the pod deployed in Kind cluster is not working

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kind

- I have dockerized a simple spring boot rest api app which lists the
  employees for /employee endpoint.
- I have created a helm chart and updated the values.yml with the image
  name, service type as NodePort and service port as 31234.
- The app is configured to run on port 8085
- Created a local docker registry in localhost 5001 and pushed the
  image to this registry. So the image name under values.yml is localhost:5001/emp and tag is latest.
- **kubectl get nodes -o wide gives:**

test-dev-control-plane   Ready    control-plane   2d23h   v1.27.3   **172.18.0.3**            Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)   5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2   containerd://1.7.1

test-dev-worker          Ready              2d23h   v1.27.3   **172.18.0.5**            Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)   5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2   containerd://1.7.1

test-dev-worker2         Ready              2d23h   v1.27.3   **172.18.0.2**            Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)   5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2   containerd://1.7.1

- **kubectl get services:**

NAME          TYPE         CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)           AGE

emp1-chart   NodePort    10.96.181.143           31234:30296/TCP   2d19h
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1               443/TCP           2d23h

- **kubectl get pods:**

NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE

abc   1/1     Running   1 (6m20s ago)   2d19h

- So when I try these url they are not working:

http://172.18.0.2:31234/employee

http://172.18.0.3:31234/employee

http://172.18.0.5:31234/employee

I can see the image in the node using the commands:

- kubectl get nodes
- docker exec -ti test-dev-worker bash
- crictl images

**It lists the image:**

localhost:5001/employee1                   latest               f784fbf148a06       532MB

helm chart values.yml:

```
replicaCount: 1
image:
  repository: localhost:5001/employee1
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: "latest"
imagePullSecrets: []
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""
serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a service account should be created
  create: true
  # Automatically mount a ServiceAccount's API credentials?
  automount: true
  # Annotations to add to the service account
  annotations: {}
  # The name of the service account to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name: ""
podAnnotations: {}
podLabels: {}
podSecurityContext: {}
  # fsGroup: 2000
securityContext: {}
  # capabilities:
  #   drop:
  #   - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  # runAsNonRoot: true
  # runAsUser: 1000
service:
  type: NodePort
  port: 31234
ingress:
  enabled: false
  className: ""
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local
resources: {}
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi
autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 100
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  # targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 80
# Additional volumes on the output Deployment definition.
volumes: []
# - name: foo
#   secret:
#     secretName: mysecret
#     optional: false
# Additional volumeMounts on the output Deployment definition.
volumeMounts: []
# - name: foo
#   mountPath: "/etc/foo"
#   readOnly: true
nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []
affinity: {}
```

Comment: "They are not working": you are getting an error? The connections are timing out? Something else?

Comment: This site can’t be reached

Comment: Is this problem specific to your application, or does this happen with anything you deploy on your cluster? Can you add a [mcve] -- a simple pod def using a stock docker image and a service -- that reproduces the problem on your environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me :)

```
kubectl port-forward <pod-name> <local-port>:<remote-port>
kubectl port-forward pods/abc 31234:8085
```

Where abc is my pod name, 31234 is the NodePort defined in helm chart values.yml which maps to the container port in my deployment.yml and 8085 is the port defined as server port in my spring boot rest api app.

Once I did that, I could see this as output:

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:31234 -> 8085
Forwarding from [::1]:31234 -> 8085
Handling connection for 31234
Handling connection for 31234
```

Then I ran my app using
http://localhost:31234/employee
This gave me the results I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `kubectl port-forward` command, adding `targetPort` as `8085` to the `service` section would have worked too. Something like below:

```yaml
service:
  type: NodePort
  port: 31234
  targetPort: 8085
```